# Bind Lightning Web Component SObject Variable to Input Text Area

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to migrate an Aura Component to a Lightning Web Component.

I am storing an sobject called "Approval_History__c" as a @track property called currentUsersHistory
I have an input test area bound to the value of currentUsersHistory.Comments__c

```
<template  if:true={canView}> ...<lightning-textarea  label="Comments" name="mycomments" value={currentUsersHistory.Comments__c} onchange={handleChange}></lightning-textarea> ...</template>
```

When I call submitResponse, I am presented with an error:

[image]
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Comments__c' of null"

Here are my initialization, handleChange and submitResponse methods:

```
 export default class approvalDecisionWebComponent extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;
@api showSpinner;
@api RecordFieldDataType;
@api canView;
@api decisionTypeValue;
@api decisionTypeLabel;
@api comments;

@track currentUsersHistory;
@track error;

connectedCallback() {
    this.initialize();

}
initialize(){        
    var decisionType;
    var decisionLabel = "Approve";
    var decisionValue = "Approved";
    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.canview = false;
    this.currentUsersHistory = null;
    
    getCurrentUserHighestApprovalHistory({recordId: this.recordId})
    .then(result => {
        if (result) { 
            if (result.Approval_Template_Step__r) {
                decisionType = result.Approval_Template_Step__r.Decision_Type__c;
            }
            if (decisionType === "Review"){
                decisionLabel = "Review";
                decisionValue = "Reviewed";
            }
            this.currentUsersHistory = result;
            this.decisionTypeLabel = decisionLabel;
            this.decisionTypeValue = decisionValue;
            this.canView = true;
            this.showSpinner = false;
            } 
            this.showSpinner = false;
            
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.showToast("Error!", "error", "error");
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    });
}


submitResponse(){
    this.showSpinner = true;
    updateRecords({recordId: this.recordId, currentUserHighestApprovalHistory: this.currentUsersHistory})
    .then(() => {
        this.showToast("Success!", "Success", "success");
        this.initialize();
        this.showSpinner = false;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.showToast("Error!", "error", "error");
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error;
        this.showSpinner = false;
    });

}

handleChange(evt) {
    const typedValue = evt.target.value;
    const trimmedValue = typedValue.trim(); // trims the value entered by the user
    if (typedValue !== trimmedValue) {
        evt.target.value = trimmedValue;
    }
    this.currentUsersHistory.Comments__c = trimmedValue; // updates the internal state
}
```

I know the updateRecords method is getting called successfully because the data is updated in the records.
I am not sure why I am getting this error here... :/

Comment: It's not clear as when is your `currentUsersHistory` gets populated before being rendered on the HTML, when is the `initialize()` function called? Based on the error seems that's always `null` and thus you cannot access the `comments__c` value.

Comment: I added some more context above - the visibility is determined by the "canView" property

Comment: So follow up question - when does `canView` turn to be `true`? And when it does, do you populate `currentUsersHistory`. I think you will need to provide more code here to be able to provide some pointers. It seems you are trying to use the `initialize()` function, but when is that called?

Comment: canView is only populated when currentUsersHistory != null. I added more code above! The initialize() is called on load and my intention is to call it again after the response is submitted.

Comment: got it all figured out! this.canview = false should have been this.canView = false; that was the problem! thanks for all the help though :)